# Raspberry Pi - Interfacing with an i2c enabled IR temp sensor (MLX90614)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

So I was recruited to my school's Baja racing team where we design build and compete with offroad dune-buggy type cars. I am a CS major and have quite a bit experience with python, and therefore was asked to help out the electrical team to interface with all of the sensors which we wanted on the car. So far so good, but now I am using an IR temperature sensor which reads ambient and object temperatures. (We are going to put this somewhere on the engine to read it's temperature and output to our GUI)

The problem is that the only libraries that seem to have used this sensor are all written in C, and normally used with arduinos... Nonetheless I compiled and edited some C code that I found online and it works great! In C. :( Since our project is completely based in python; I'd really like some help reading this sensor via i2c and Python, although I really don't have a ton of experience in writing libraries, especially not for electronics. Any tips would be great to steer me in the correct direction. Here is the C code that we are currently using that I basically want the same thing in Python:

```
    //fordit:  gcc MLXi2c.c -o i2c -l bcm2835
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
#define AVG 1   //averaging samples
#define LOGTIME 10  //loging period
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char buf[6];
    unsigned char i,reg;
    double temp=0,calc=0, skytemp,atemp;
    FILE *flog;
    flog=fopen("mlxlog.csv", "a");..
    bcm2835_init();
    bcm2835_i2c_begin();
    bcm2835_i2c_set_baudrate(25000);.
    // set address...........................................................................................
    bcm2835_i2c_setSlaveAddress(0x5a);
....
    printf("\nOk, your device is working!!\n");
....
....
    while(1) {
        time_t t = time(NULL);
<------>struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
<------>calc=0;
<------>reg=7;
<------>for(i=0;i<AVG;i++){
<------>    bcm2835_i2c_begin();
<------>    bcm2835_i2c_write (&reg, 1);
<------>    bcm2835_i2c_read_register_rs(&reg,&buf[0],3);
<------>    temp = (double) (((buf[1]) << 8) + buf[0]);
<------>    temp = (temp * 0.02)-0.01;
    <-->    temp = temp - 273.15;
<------>    calc+=temp;
<------>    sleep(1);
<------>    }
<------>skytemp=calc/AVG;
<------>calc=0;
<------>reg=6;
<------>for(i=0;i<AVG;i++){
<------>    bcm2835_i2c_begin();
<------>    bcm2835_i2c_write (&reg, 1);
<------>    bcm2835_i2c_read_register_rs(&reg,&buf[0],3);
<------>    temp = (double) (((buf[1]) << 8) + buf[0]);
<------>    temp = (temp * 0.02)-0.01;
    <-->    temp = temp - 273.15;
<------>    calc+=temp;
<------>    sleep(1);
<------>    }
<------>atemp=calc/AVG;
<------>printf("%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n    Tambi=%04.2f C, Tobj=%04.2f C\n", tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec,atemp,skytemp);
<------>fprintf(flog,"%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d,%04.2f,%04.02f\n",tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_mon +1, tm.tm_mday,tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec,atemp,skytemp);
<------>fflush(flog);
<------>sleep(LOGTIME-(2*AVG));
    }
...
    printf("[done]\n");
}
```

thanks in advance!

- Eddie

Comment: Why not simply call the C program from python instead of rewriting the whole thing?

Comment: I was unaware you could do that? Would you mind elaborating? 

I actually thought of this if somehow I could get the returned value from the C program into python, I would be golden.

Comment: If you have a program that doesn't run infinitely, it's as easy as `import subprocess; sens_val = subprocess.check_output(["path_to_your_c_program"])`

If your C program DOES run infinitely (e.g. in a `while(1)` loop like it would on an arduino), you could simply remove that loop so it only fetches a single sensor reading per execution, prints it to stdout and exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Changes:**

- removed `while(1)` - only one reading per execution. If the sensor requires repeated start, a for/while loop might be needed; just don't make it an infinite loop unless you plan on killing the process from python.
- the last `printf` now outputs a JSON string delimited by a starting and ending pipe/|
- added `return 0;` to `main()` so python's subprocess module knows
  what's up
- removed comments and full stops that caused compiler errors (low level C experts, are the full stops significant?)

Save this as **mlx90614_query.c** and compile:

```
//fordit:  gcc mlx90614_query.c -o mlx90614_query -l bcm2835
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#define AVG 1   //averaging samples
#define LOGTIME 10  //loging period

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char buf[6];
    unsigned char i,reg;
    double temp=0,calc=0, skytemp,atemp;
    FILE *flog;
    flog=fopen("mlxlog.csv", "a");
    bcm2835_init();
    bcm2835_i2c_begin();
    bcm2835_i2c_set_baudrate(25000);
    // set address
    bcm2835_i2c_setSlaveAddress(0x5a);

    printf("\nOk, your device is working!!\n");

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    calc=0;
    reg=7;

    for(i=0;i<AVG;i++){
        bcm2835_i2c_begin();
        bcm2835_i2c_write (&reg, 1);
        bcm2835_i2c_read_register_rs(&reg,&buf[0],3);
        temp = (double) (((buf[1]) << 8) + buf[0]);
        temp = (temp * 0.02)-0.01;
        temp = temp - 273.15;
        calc+=temp;
        sleep(1);
    }

    skytemp=calc/AVG;
    calc=0;
    reg=6;

    for(i=0;i<AVG;i++){
        bcm2835_i2c_begin();
        bcm2835_i2c_write (&reg, 1);
        bcm2835_i2c_read_register_rs(&reg,&buf[0],3);
        temp = (double) (((buf[1]) << 8) + buf[0]);
        temp = (temp * 0.02)-0.01;
        temp = temp - 273.15;
        calc+=temp;
        sleep(1);
    }

    atemp=calc/AVG;

    printf("|{\"time\":{\"month\":\"%02d\",\"day\":\"%02d\",\"hour\":\"%02d\",\"min\":\"%02d\",\"sec\":\"%02d\"},\"data\":{\"t_ambi\":\"%04.2f\",\"t_obj\":\"%04.2f\"}}|\n", tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec,atemp,skytemp);

    fprintf(flog,"%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d,%04.2f,%04.02f\n",tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_mon +1, tm.tm_mday,tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec,atemp,skytemp);

    fflush(flog);
    sleep(LOGTIME-(2*AVG));

    printf("[done]\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Your C program now outputs your existing debug messages plus this json ("|" used as delimiter):

```
{
    "time": {
        "month": "03",
        "day": "09",
        "hour": "20",
        "min": "24",
        "sec": "28"
    },
    "data": {
        "t_ambi": "77.77",
        "t_obj": "34.44"
    }
}
```

Save this as a python script in the same folder as mlx90614_query (the extra spaces will cause trouble if you copy/paste to an interactive interpreter):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import subprocess
import sys

sensor_dict = {}

py3 = False

# python version check determines string handling

try:
    if (sys.version_info > (3, 0)):
        py3 = True    
except:
    pass

try:

    subp_ret = subprocess.check_output(["./mlx90614_query"])

    # at this point, subprocess succeeded and subp_ret holds your output 

    if py3:
        subp_ret = subp_ret.decode('utf8')

    sensor_dict = json.loads(subp_ret.split("|")[1].strip())

    # cast temperatures to float and print

    for k in sensor_dict["data"]:
        val = float(sensor_dict["data"][k]) 
        sensor_dict["data"][k] = val  
        print (k, "\t", val) 

    # cast date/time segments to int and print

    for k in sensor_dict["time"]:
        val = int(sensor_dict["time"][k])
        sensor_dict["time"][k] = val  
        print (k, "\t", val)         

    # Now go win that race! :P

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Output:

```
$ gcc mlx90614_query.c -o mlx90614_query -l bcm2835
$

$ ./mlx90614_query
Ok, your device is working!!
|{"time":{"month":"03","day":"09","hour":"21","min":"45","sec":"53"},"data":{"t_ambi":"0.00","t_obj":"0.00"}}|
[done]


$ python3.4 mlx_print.py 
t_obj    34.44
t_ambi   77.77
hour     21
sec      33
min      58
month    3
day      9

$ python2 mlx_print.py 
t_ambi   77.77
t_obj    34.44
min      58
sec      37
day      9
hour     21
month    3
```

Sorry for stealing your homework - Just <3 to code :D

Comment: Thank you so much! The team thanks you sincerely. Although one question, is there a way I can speed it up? When i run mlx_print.py it takes ~10 seconds to actually output any data, does this have something to do with the sampling average? Thanks you

Comment: You're welcome :) Weird about the delay though. I didn't go into the low level i2C stuff and don't have your sensor so I can't do much testing either. It could be the sampling average but it's hard to say from my position - I'll see if the internet has more info on the matter. When I ran the script + c program with some random hard-coded values, it returned immediately. Have you tried running the c program on its own a couple of times? Is it delayed without the python script? Always?

Comment: Try compiling [this one](http://pastebin.com/raw/PnLVC44v) instead and see if it changes anything. I literally only removed the while loop and added the return statement this time; no clean-up or anything else (I might have introduced a subtle bug the last time). You can probably get rid of `sleep(LOGTIME-(2*AVG));` but try it as-is first.

Comment: error during compiling /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbcm2835